# Calling pivot model method in relationship chaining Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have five Models: `User`, `City`, `State`, `ResidencePivot`, `PrivacyType`

1. `User` Model has `ManyToMany` relationship with `City` Model through `residences()` method using `ResidencePivot` Model
2. `City` Model has `OneToMany` relationship with `State` Model through `state()` method **(i.e `City => (BelongsTo) => State`)**
3. `ResidencePivot` has `OneToMany` relationship with `PrivacyType` Model through `privacyType()` method **(i.e `ResidencePivot => (BelongsTo) => City`)**

I am calling relationships on `User` Model like this:

```
$user->load('residences.state')
```

This gives me all the city residences where user have ever lived along with states but I also want to get the privacy of these residences. Since, the method to get the privacy of these residences is in `ResidencePivot` Model. How can I chain the relationship in above code statement?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many relations as you want as long they're declared:

```
$user->load('residences.state','residences.privacyType')
```

Also you may also use Eager loading depending on the situation if you want to load all the data in in the same query as you get the User:

```
$user = User::with('residences.state','residences.privacyType')->find($id);
```

Comment: In your first statement, `residences.privacyType` gives error because it can't find `privacyType()` method in `City` Model. Remember, it is not defined on `City` Model but on `ResidencePivot` Model which extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`

Comment: Oh I see, could you post the structure of you schema in DB? To see the actual columns. You also can add an extra query to get the desired parameters: `User::with(['residences' => function($query) { $query->with('state')->addSelect(...your query to related table)}])->find($id);`

Comment: Actually, I solved it :) The pivot table method can be called on the `pivot` key of data collection after fetching `ManyToMany` relationship